# Exporting Sprint Capacity from Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, devops

[Capacity View in Devops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOXQw.png) I am trying to export the Script Capacity of different teams from Azure DevOps.

Do we have a way to get the report from a report or a chart for the Capacity added for a sprint?

Comment: I think you can read out these data over the REST API [Capacities - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/capacities/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0). After that you could visualize a chart by your self.

Comment: Do you want to export the Capacity from **different teams** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API to get that data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/capacities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I connected this API with PowerBI, but you can build a Website or use another platform to visualize and manipulate the data coming from the API.

This is also a good article explaining the work it can be done in PowerBI: https://vinijmoura.medium.com/how-to-viewing-individual-capacities-on-different-projects-teams-and-sprints-in-azure-devops-d369c6f14155